# Why does my regex work in .NET but not in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, forms

I am using an asp RegularExpressionValidator to validate if a textarea has html or encoded html.  I need the validator to work client side because I have ValidateRequest set to true on the page.  My regex is set to match any string that does not have a less than character followed by an alpha character or an ampersand followed by some number of alpha characters ending in a semi-colon.

```
^((?![<]{1}[a-z]{1}).)*$
^((?![&]{1}[a-z]+;).)*$
```

Comment: Why are you using `{1}`? It's redundant. I'm not sure what that's meant to do, but `{x}` doesn't do anything unless x is 2 or greater.

Comment: By the way, unless you just need something quick & dirty and aren't worried about accuracy, [regex is the wrong tool for validating HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/399649). If this is for something important, like protecting against XSS, regex won't cut it. For example, `<   script>` will get past your pattern because of the whitespace. Use a real HTML parser instead.

Comment: It is ok if < script gets past the client side validation.  It is not valid html, anyway, and shouldn't be an issue even if it were saved to the database.  I am doing more validation server side.  I just need this client side validation to work so my end users don't get hit with the application error page.

Comment: `< script src="http://foo.bar">` is valid HTML. The whitespace after the `<` doesn't matter.

Comment: Negative.  Try the following code on a test html page.  It will render the text as plain text in the browser but not execute the script:
< script>alert("");</script>

Comment: Well, I'll be! Looks like it applies to all HTML tags as well. Thanks, you've taught me something new. I would caution you that not all browsers are standards-compliant, but as long as you have stronger server-side validation, you should be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript does not have a concept of Single-Line which lets your period match any character including line breaks.  You should use the following in place of your comma: [\s\S]

```
^((?![<]{1}[a-z]{1})[\s\S])*$
^((?![&]{1}[a-z]+;)[\s\S])*$
```

Comment: Thanks.  That was the answer I was looking for.